# ASP.NET HttpContext Items vanish on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, httpcontext

We are currently seeing an issue with the use of `HttpContext.Current.Items` where the local environments of the developers show no issues (all works as expected) in the server environment we are suddenly loosing items placed inside (getting a `NullReferenceException`).

I sketched some code and use below:

Global.asax we initialise the factory at BeginRequest:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Items["Key"] = new Factory();
}
```

Inside the `BaseControl` we have a property to retrieve the factory easily:

```
public Factory Factory
{
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Items["Key"] as Factory; }
}
```

In the `UserControl` we use it through the base property:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Product p = Factory.CreateProduct();
}
```

Environment information:

- Local DEVs are running on Windows 7 and 8 using IIS 7.5 and 8 and Sitecore 6.6
- The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 using IIS 7.5 and Sitecore 6.6

For all local DEVs (we're working on this project with 6 people) there's no issue with the code described above. However once we deploy the code to the test server the locations that use the Factory break (ea the `HttpContext.Current.Items` is empty)

Comment: perhaps an applicationpool restart?

Comment: @JPHellemons If it would be due to an applicationpool restart the entire page should not render, only the components that use the factory are returning errors.

Comment: @IvanL have you tried `Application_AcquireRequestState`? I would suspect `Application_BeginRequest` is being invoked on all requests (even for CSS, javascript, etc) and `HttpContext.Current` may not be available in some cases. AquireRequestState happens later in the pipeline, and may provide more reliable access to `HttpContext.Current.Items`. Just a guess...

Comment: @DerekHunziker I will give it a try, sadly we're on a tight shedule so for now we have created a workaround

Comment: @IvanL did you find a solution to this problem?  I'm having exactly the same issue

Comment: @Webbie4 No we never resolved this issue and left the workaround in place

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine only 1 scenario when it behaves like you described: in the `Global.asax` file the `Inherits` property on the test server points to the `Sitecore.Web.Application` directly omitting your code execution.

Could you double check if the `Global.asax` file starts with

```
<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="My.Assembly.Namespace.Global" %>
```

This could happen if the `Global.asax` was changed in your dev enironment but hasn't been deployed to the test environment.

If it's not an issue, try to check if the `Application_BeginRequest` is executed on the test server. It would give you an answer whether the `Factory` is never added to `HttpContext.Current.Items` or whether it's removed from the `Items` during the request handling.

Comment: We verified this: The global.asax file inheritance is correct, we also did a Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info and verified that the code is being executed.

Comment: Can you try with the string variable passed to the `Items` instead of `Factory` instance? And also try logging `Request.RawUrl` for both `BeginRequest` method and `Factory` getter?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you use the same name for your property as it's type:

```
public Factory Factory {}
```

Maybe this initiates some unexpected behavior?

Comment: No, the actual code has different class - property names, the shown names are simplified.